# 19.10 Server: Setting a static IP

Tags: server

I am in the early stages of setting up a test server using Ubuntu Server 19.10 and have ran into a problem I don't know how to solve. I am trying to set a static IP during the initial setup and keep getting the error shown in the screenshot.

I've tried multiple different configurations, and none of them have worked. Any advice on what needs to be entered?

https://gyazo.com/400cf73c2052bf37fea38da9b2c20740

Comment: @K7AAY 19.10

If I remove the /24 it gives me the message "should be in CIDR format xx.xx.xx.xx/yy

Answer (score 0):

From this site http://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php you can determine what your CIDR Address would be for your subnet.  Remember that a `/24` is what you set your **Mask Bits** to.

[image]

Your subnet line for your subnet should be `10.1.1.0/24` (which is your Net: CIDR Notation) for your network with a gateway of `10.1.1.1` and your IP address of `10.1.1.169`